# Cartesian equation of star shape

Tags: graphics

I need Cartesian equation of the following star shape. As i want to use its Cartesian equation for Plot3D.

[image]

Comment: What *Mathematica* code have you used to plot the image in your question? What *Mathematica* issue are you encountering?

Comment: Thanks Mr. Jens, As you can see in Mathematica help,  For Plot3D , we need to give bounds in the form of cartesian coordinates, thats why i need to find its cartesian equation,

Comment: I needed its cartesian equation as i want to find its interior points

Comment: As for the Cartesian equation… I normally use `GroebnerBasis[]` for deriving this. This will likely be a very high-degree algebraic equation that will be too unwieldy to manipulate.

Comment: how can i derive cartesian equation using GroebnerBasis[]

Answer (score 9):

Another way to parameterize this curve is to recognize that it is a sine wave (of 18 cycles) plotted around the unit circle. One concise representation of the unit circle is with the real and imaginary parts of the complex exponential Exp[I 2 Pi t]. Hence:

```
f[t_] := Exp[I t ] (1 + 0.15 Sin[18 t + Pi/2]);
ParametricPlot[{Re[f[t]], Im[f[t]]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

Guess_who_it_is suggests the even simpler version

```
PolarPlot[1 + 0.15 Sin[18 t + Pi/2], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

which gives the same plot.

Comment: …or use `PolarPlot[]`. ;)

Answer (score 8):

You'll need to set the radius of the curve (`r`) that goes through the center of the cosine waves and the desired number of peaks (`a`)

```
r = 6;
a = 18;
ListPlot[Table[{(r + Cos[a 2 π i/360]) Cos[2 π i/360] ,
                (r + Cos[a 2 π i/360]) Sin[2 π i/360]}, {i, 360}],
         AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: star shape]

Comment: The same, shorter `r = 6; a = 18; n = 360;
ListPlot[(r + Cos[a #]) {Cos@#, Sin@#} & /@ Range[0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/n], 
 AspectRatio -> 1]`

Answer (score 7):

Convert polar equation to use Intrinsic equation and ContourPlot:

```
ContourPlot[
 1 + 1/8 Sin[18 ArcTan[x, y]] == Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], {x, -1.15, 
  1.15}, {y, -1.15, 1.15}, Axes -> True]
```

[image]